About the condition for using the Taylor expansion at a point
I'm slightly confused about the requirement for using the Taylor expansion. Suppose we have a function $f$ that is only $n$ times differentiable but not $C^{n}$ on an interval $I$ containing a point $x_0$. Can we then write $f$ in the following form? $$\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(x_{0})}{k!}(x-x_{0})^{k} + o((x-x_{0})^{n})
\end{align*}$$
Let $1 < i \leq k$. First, I notice that if I want to have $f^{(i)}(x_0)$, I must have $f^{(i-1)}$ exist on the interval $I$, so we can define $f^{(i)}$ at the point $x_0$ by the limit. However, we know that there exist functions that are differentiable at a point but not differentiable (or even not continuous) on any neighborhood around that point. In many contexts, I have seen that we need $f$ to be $C^n$ on an interval containing $x_0$ in order to have the above expansion.
Since the existence of the derivative of a function $f$ at a point does not require differentiability (or even continuity) of $f$ around that point, I am wondering whether we can allow $f$ to be $n$ times differentiable on $I$ but not necessarily continuous?

If the function is $C^n$ continuous over an interval, you can approximate it with a polynomial of degree $n$ or less on that interval.  If the derivatives are not continuous beyond that point, you should not apply a higher degree polynomial.

All this fuss about continuous differentiability is a red herring. If the first $n$ derivatives of $f$ exist at $x_0$, then the $n^{\text{th}}$ degree Taylor polynomial at $x_0$, $P_n$, is defined, and
$$f(x)=P_n(x) + o((x-x_0)^n).$$
This assertion does not require that $f$ be $C^n$ at $a$, although it will follow that $f$ must be $C^{n-1}$ at $a$.
If you want more precise control of the error on an interval $[a,b]$, then typically we require that $f$ be $(n+1)$ times differentiable on the interval and we get
$$f(x)=P_n(x) + R_n(x), \ x\in [a,b],$$ with $$R_n(x) = \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1} \text{  for some  }c\in (a,x).$$
Of course, with this differentiability hypothesis, $f\in C^n$ on the interval.
There is also the integral form of the remainder, now with the  hypothesis that $f$ be $C^{n+1}$ on the interval:
$$R_n(x) = \int_a^x \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n\,dt.$$
The continuity hypothesis enters here to be sure that the integrand is integrable.
